# How to avoid terraform vpc module to create route table for each subnet?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-modules

I have created vpc and its components using the official vpc module as shown below. The problem is that each subnet has its own route table. I want to create 2 route tables lets say private and public and attach subnets to it.
rt-private: subnet1,subnet2
rt-public: subnet3,subnet4

```html
module "vpc" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version         = "2.77.0"
  name            = "${var.vpc_name}"
  cidr            = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  azs             = "${var.azs}"
  private_subnets = "${var.private_subnets}"
  #public_subnets  = "${var.public_subnets}"

  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  enable_nat_gateway = false
  #  single_nat_gateway = true
  create_igw = false

  vpc_tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
    Automated   = "Terraform"
    Owner       = "${var.owner}"
    Project     = "${var.project}"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
    Automated   = "Terraform"
    Owner       = "${var.owner}"
    Project     = "${var.project}"
  }

  public_subnet_tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
    Automated   = "Terraform"
    Owner       = "${var.owner}"
    Project     = "${var.project}"
  }

  private_route_table_tags = {
    #Name        = "${var.private_route_table_tags}"
    Environment = "${var.env}"
    Automated   = "Terraform"
    Owner       = "${var.owner}"
    Project     = "${var.project}"
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with a single route table per type of subnet? It's a bit cleaner but the impact should be the same here and having a route table per subnet in the module allows them to more easily handle using a NAT gateway per AZ.

Comment: It’s a customer requirement so.

Comment: Your requirement is not supported by this module. You either have to fork it and modify, or create entire VPC setup from scratch tailored to your customer's needs.